# jquery ow-carousel resize issue

Tags: jquery, html, owl-carousel

im working with image carousel using owl-carousel. there are two carousel.one is full width carousel and another one is overlayed above. single "next,prev" button for controlling both carousels. its a responsive one. if i resize the window the overlayed carousel should resize according to the full width carousel.

[this is demo](http://54.191.94.248/test/nested-slider/)

please anyone tell me, how to solve this issue or suggest me any carousel plugins to make the new one looks like this.